# Is there a way to display elapsed time from two timestamps in js?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, timestamp, solidity

i'm currently struggling with time operations in js. I'm getting an elapsed time from outside the js app.

Let's say I have the calculation of the elapsed time between two timestamps from another service and i want to display it in my html file.

Is there a way to extract days, hours, minutes and seconds from the elapsed time and generate some kind of a clock that keeps adding seconds continuosly?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using something as [dayjs](https://day.js.org/) for manipulating data with Javascript, it's much easier than the default API.

For the clock behavior you can use `setInterval(()=>{},1000)` to update it every second